# Minimum required version management

Tags: c#, assemblies, version

I have 3 assemblies - 2 of them applications and 1 class library (both applications use the class library).

One application is a "client", which uses a data file created by the other application. However, I would like to check if the client can use the data file (e.g. if the data file does not utilize stuff from new versions of the client and/or class library).

I thought I could just use version of the client application but the version information has to be created by the "creator" application.

Edit: I thought the question was clear, even though I didn't write one.

So, how should I save version of client application and class library needed to open and work with the data file?

This version needs to be accessible from the editing application - however I would like to avoid having to enter it manually.

Answer (score 2):

No, I would suggest to check for *data file version*, and **not** *assembly version* that creates that data-file. For simply reason, that assembly can change it version, not because the data-file format (say) changed, but for some bugfix, but data-file remained the same.

In short:

During the generation of data-file, write in the header/manifest a `data-file version` information and based on *that* information choose the right version for your importer/converter/whatever is it..

Comment: Well, data importer will most likely not change in the future (and by extent the data file). However, new functionality will be added into the class library. Thus it could happen that older version of client application will try to use data file, which uses new functionality of the class library.

Comment: hm.. data-file can not *use* anything, it's just raw-data. Clients can have different versions. If you mean that the data-file format can changed, it's by the way, better to relay on its version that not necessary can reflect the version of the client tat creates it.

Comment: You still don't understand, what my problem is. Data file format is unlikely to change, but functionality of class library and/or client application will. Thus data file does not have any version, rather the class library and client application has.

Comment: OK, so `data-file` as is, has no any relation with this question. Cause what an vary in time is a code/management of the "stuff" inside clients. If so  and you need to make them communicate, there is no other way the make some `IVersion` interface (or just assembly built-in version information) on both of clients, and so they can query each other.

Comment: However, those two applications don't ever communicate with each other - data file is created and then client application uses it separately.

Comment: @mnn: so we came back, at this point. IF two client don't communicate with each other, `data-file` (say) never changed, why do you worry about versioning problem at all ?

Comment: You still seem not to understand my problem. Data file **changes**, but its _format_ **does not**. New features are added, and older versions of clients might try to open such data file, that uses those new features - I want to be able to check if the client's version and class library's version is at least the version used to created this particular data file.

Comment: No idea how you add features without changing the file format.

Comment: As Chaos mantioned, if **only** the data in the file changed (say you have 2 column inside with strings "a", "b" and tomorrow you have the same 2 columns, but with "c" and "b" data) .. Who cares anout different version?  I have **suspect** that who reads content "a, b, c, d"  behaves in different way if there is "a" or "c". If so, *this* can be counted like a format change, like you (say) added a new column to a file. Handle this in the same way: in `data-file` inject data-file's version. Operate on `data-file` cause it's a single "bridge" between those two clients.

Comment: Well, since you still don't understand my issue, it seems I'm on my own. Well thanks for input anyway.